# Extracting a subtree from a BST - Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-search-tree, subtree

Let's say you have a binary search tree:

`t (73, t (31, t(5,nil,nil), nil), t (101, t (83, nil, t(97,nil,nil)), t(200,nil,nil)))`

which is:

```
                73
             /     \
            31     101
           /      /   \
          5      83  200
                    /
                   97
```

I need to write a predicate **subtree(X1,X2,T)** that would take `2` values from the tree **(X1 and X2)** and find the smallest common parent for them, and store its subtree in T.

So for the example above, if I query : 
**subtree(83,200,X).**

I should be getting back:

```
t(101,t(83,nil,t(97,nil,nil)),t(200,nil,nil))
```

which is:

```
                   101
                  /   \
                 83  200
                    /
                   97
```

Since `101` is the smallest common value to both of my numbers, I get that subtree back.
How could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The general steps can be the following:

1. Find path from the root to the first element
2. Do the same for the second element
3. The paths should share some elements at the beginning. The last common element is the root of the subtree.
4. Extract the subtree from the root.

I hope this is enough help.

Comment: yeah i understand that's the general idea i'm just not too sure about the code.. no idea on how to write it.